# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniTest in java.library.path Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, javacpp

I am trying a Maven Project with javacpp from Eclipse, and the project builds, but when I try to run it, it gives an exception and terminates itself. I am pretty new to Maven and managing pom.xml files, and I don't know what to do. The exception is:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniTest in java.library.path:`

```
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1683)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1300)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1123)
    at com.berk.maventest.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:13)
```

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.berk</groupId>
  <artifactId>maventest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
 
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacpp-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
      <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1-1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And my Test.java file:

```
package com.berk.maventest;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include = "Test.cpp")

@Namespace("TestLibrary")

public class Test extends Pointer{
    
    static {
        Loader.load();
    }
    
    public Test()
    {
        allocate();
    }
    
    private native void allocate();
    
    public native int testMethod(int a);
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        //Calling the constructor
        Test test = new Test();
        
        //Calling the function
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + test.testMethod(2));
        
        //Calling the destructor
        test.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When running it, you missed to specify the directory containing the native library `jniTest`: `java ... -Djava.library.path=path/to/dir`.

Comment: You'll need to run the build steps of JavaCPP. For Maven, you can check how it's done for the Presets, but it's a lot easier with Gradle: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#getting-started